# Where can I find shapefiles for the rivers of Puerto Rico?

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial

I would like to find shapefile data for all of the rivers in Puerto Rico.  This could be as a subset of the rivers in the United States.  I already have an accurate boundary of the island.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here are the **open data sets** that match your requirements:

- [Data.gov's Puerto Rico hydrography data (shapefile format)](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?metadata_type=geospatial&ext_location=Puerto+Rico&tags=hydrography&q=river&ext_bbox=-67.942726%2C17.926405%2C-65.242737%2C18.520166&ext_prev_extent=-69.01611328125%2C16.109153239219467%2C-64.18212890625%2C20.282808691330054&sort=score+desc%2C+name+asc&res_format=shapefile)
- [Data.gov's Puerto Rico hydrography data (all formats)](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?metadata_type=geospatial&ext_location=Puerto+Rico&tags=hydrography&q=river&ext_bbox=-67.942726%2C17.926405%2C-65.242737%2C18.520166&ext_prev_extent=-69.01611328125%2C16.109153239219467%2C-64.18212890625%2C20.282808691330054&sort=score+desc%2C+name+asc)

Seems to be the **same data sets**, but available *via geoplatform.gov site*:

- [Puerto Rico hydrography data (shapefile format)](https://www.geoplatform.gov/node/201/%26fq%3Dmetadata_type%3A%22geospatial%22%2BAND%2B%26fq%3Dres_format%3A%22shapefile%22%20AND%20metadata_type%3A%22geospatial%22%20AND%20%26fq%3Dres_format%3A%22shapefile%22%20AND%20tags%3A%22hydrography%22%20AND%20metadata_type%3A%22geospatial%22%20AND%20%26keyword%3Drivers%26sort%3D%26ext_bbox%3D17.926405%2C-67.942726%2C18.520166%2C-65.242737%26ext_location%3DPuerto%20Rico)
- [Puerto Rico hydrography data (all formats)](https://www.geoplatform.gov/node/201/%26fq%3Dmetadata_type%3A%22geospatial%22%2BAND%2B%26fq%3Dtags%3A%22hydrography%22%20AND%20metadata_type%3A%22geospatial%22%20AND%20%26keyword%3Drivers%26sort%3D%26ext_bbox%3D17.926405%2C-67.942726%2C18.520166%2C-65.242737%26ext_location%3DPuerto%20Rico#addinfo)

Finally, [these Puerto Rico hydrography data sets](http://data.geocomm.com/catalog/RQ/group105.html) are in [ESRI ArcInfo interchange file (E00)](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000291.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

I found the Puerto Rico GIS centre's pages at http://www2.pr.gov/agencias/gis/Pages/default.aspx. Sadly I don't speak enough (any) Spanish to work out if there are any data files there but I did find a WMS of the hydrography, which suggests there is likely to be a shapefile somewhere.

http://gis.otg.pr.gov/ArcGIS/services/Basemap/Hydrography/mapserver/WMSServer